# Passing variables when instantiating a form class using FormWizard

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple form which uses a queryset that is set dynamically:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    bar = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Bar.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['bar'].queryset = queryset
```

I'd like to use this as one of my forms in a `FormWizard`, but I can't figure out how I can get `FormWizard` to pass on the queryset. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could override the "get_form" method for that particular wizard

```
class MyWizard(FormWizard):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.querysets = kwargs.pop('querysets', None)
        super(self, MyWizard).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, step, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
      return self.form_list[step](data, prefix=self.prefix_for_step(step), initial=self.initial.get(step, None), queryset=self.querysets.get(step, None))

    def done(self, *args, **kwargs): pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a feasible workaround. In the `FormWizard` code it says explicitly "SHOULDN'T OVERRIDE" for `__init__` or `get_form`, but I don't see a better way to do this. It looks like this might be supported in the development version looking at the docs, but I still don't see explicitly how to implement it. Anyways, thanks again!